# Assigning Google Sheet Values to Object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having difficulty with manipulating data imported from Google Sheets into an object. Whenever I check the code using, Logger.log(myObject), I get a return value of:

> [18-03-06 21:52:55:530 PST] master schedule = [object Object]

**How do I import from Google Sheets such that it's not displayed as [object Object]? I'd like to be able to manipulate the data!**

Here's a sample of the code:

```
// Object based schedule production
function createNewSchedule () {
  var requestSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Requests");
  var newScheduleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("NewSchedule");
  var lastColumn = requestSheet.getLastColumn(); //30 columns

  var requestData = availableDocsData();
  var availDocs;
  var counter = 0;
  var masterSchedule = {};

  //resetting the masterSchedule to temporary values.
  var resetMasterSchedule = {};
  var temp1 = newScheduleSheet.getRange(2, 1, 11, 1).getValues();
  temp1 = arrayDeconvert(temp1);
  var temp2 = newScheduleSheet.getRange(2, 2, 11, 1).getValues();
  temp2 = arrayDeconvert(temp2);
  var temp3 = newScheduleSheet.getRange(2, 3, 11, 1).getValues();
  temp3 = arrayDeconvert(temp3);
  var temp4 = newScheduleSheet.getRange(2, 4, 11, 1).getValues();
  temp4 = arrayDeconvert(temp4);
  var temp5 = newScheduleSheet.getRange(2, 5, 11, 1).getValues();
  temp5 = arrayDeconvert(temp5);
  resetMasterSchedule["temp1"] = temp1;
  resetMasterSchedule["temp2"] = temp2;
  resetMasterSchedule["temp3"] = temp3;
  resetMasterSchedule["temp4"] = temp4;
  resetMasterSchedule["temp5"] = temp5;
  masterSchedule = resetMasterSchedule;

  // Loop makes day by day schedule
  for (var i = 1; i <= lastColumn-1; i++) {

    Logger.log ('master schedule = ' + masterSchedule);

var currentDay = [];

//finding the previous day, prevDay, given i.
var prevKeyi = i - 1;
var prevKey = Object.keys(masterSchedule)[prevKeyi];
var prevDay = masterSchedule[prevKey];

// ... I can supply additional code if needed
```

here's the function arrayDeconvert():

```
// convert Google Sheets format to regular javascript array format
function arrayDeconvert(array) {
  var newArray = [].concat.apply([], array);
  return newArray;
}
```

my function always breaks on this other function, *contains()*, which calls on the variable, *prevDay*, which is a value stored in the object, *masterSchedule*. When it tries to compute the length of *prevDay*, it's unable to because it is UNDEFINED...

```
// returns true if array contains object, starting at position x.
function contains(a, obj, x) {
  for (var i = x; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] === obj) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you avoid your array "conversion", you can use just a single, multicell getValues call. `vals[row][col]` is pretty convenient: for a given day *`col`*, the previous day is `col - 1`. You'd drop the need for `tempN`. Without seeing how you use prevDay, it's hard to say what other improvements you could make.

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have issues in my answer, feel free to tell me. Such information helps me to study. Also I think that it helps other users to know the situation as an information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

### For question 1 :

I think that the reason of `master schedule = [object Object]` is due to that the object tries to be used as a string. If you want to see the object, please try as follows.

```
Logger.log(masterSchedule)
```

or

```
Logger.log('master schedule = ' + JSON.stringify(masterSchedule))
```

### For question 2 :

In your script,5 properties from `temp1` to `temp5` is imported to `resetMasterSchedule`. On the other hand, at `var lastColumn = requestSheet.getLastColumn(); //30 columns`, you say that `lastColumn` is 30.

This means that your script tries to retrieve 30 properties from the object with 5 properties. By this, after the 5th property is retrieved, `undefined` is returned.

For your script, if you want to retrieve all properties from `masterSchedule`, how about this?

```
var len = Object.keys(masterSchedule).length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  var prevKey = Object.keys(masterSchedule)[i];
  var prevDay = masterSchedule[prevKey];
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.